# Specifying schema name while creating ConnectionPool

Tags: database, database-connection, datasource, connection-pooling

I am using the commons-dbcp2 library for JdbcConnectionPooling:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When i am initializing the connection pool i am binding it with Schema Name by making the schema name as part of URL as:

```
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    String url = "<url>";
    ds.setDriverClassName("<DriverClass>");
    ds.setUsername("<userName>");
    ds.setPassword("<Password>");
    ds.setInitialSize(5);
    ds.setMaxTotal(10);
    ds.setMaxIdle(5);
    String schema = "<mySchema>";
    ds.setUrl(url + "?currentschema=" + schema);
    try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection()) {
    }catch(Exception ex){
    LOG.error("Issue while creating connection pool", ex);
    }
```

Is this correct way of creating the connectionpool (By binding the connection pool to a schema name)? What is the impact if i try to run a query [with the connection borrowed from the pool] on another schema?

Answer (score 0):

I would say schema name shouldn't be part of URL since db connections are made to databases and not to schema per se. Also, there are data bases like DB2 where `currentschema` wouldn't work.

We should  keep in mind the basic purposes behind the concept of schema - organization of tables - functionally and user - wise and we shouldn't start associating it with connections.

As per schema permissions granted, a user would be able to connect to only specific schema and user should mandatory use schema name in all of queries. Queries shouldn't be ambiguous.

For your second  question,

> What is the impact if i try to run a query [with the connection
>   borrowed from the pool] on another schema?

I think, you can very well test it out and my guess is it shouldn't work but behavior might vary from database to database.

I say that it wouldn't work because of this note on setUrl method-

> Note: this method currently has no effect once the pool has been
>   initialized. The pool is initialized the first time one of the
>   following methods is invoked: getConnection, setLogwriter,
>   setLoginTimeout, getLoginTimeout, getLogWriter.

It shouldn't work because URL once supplied wouldn't automatically change for second schema. Pooling API should simply pass on that previous URL to new query executions and it might work/not work depending on underlying drivers / dbs.

In these APIs, a method like , `setSchema()` not being provided may have its own reasons - your code should be as neutral as possible.

Hope it helps !!